# Copying or creating object?

Tags: python-3.x, optimization

Just a thought that came to my mind. What is more efficient? Making a **new instance** of an Object , or creating a **copy** of an object?

```
import copy

class Object():
    a = 1
    b = 2

# creating the "original" object
obj = Object()

# what is better? copy?
obj2 = copy.deepcopy(obj)

# or new object
obj3 = Object()
```

What takes more processing time?

Comment: it depends, copying the object certainly takes more time since it is instantiation + copying of its fields/parameters, whereas the alternatives (so far in question) are only instantiation. However when indeed a copy of an object is desired the built-in copy will be in general faster than hand-written copy

Comment: Did you check how much time it takes? Also note that this vastly depends on *what* object you are trying to clone. This ``Object`` does not even have an initialiser, so it is relatively cheap to create. At the same time, it does not hold data either, so it is relatively cheap to copy as well.

Comment: Look at what deepcopy does https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy, it is very much not the same as just instantiating an object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like copying is a lot slower

```
import copy
import time

class Boat():
    a = 1
    b = 2

ship = Boat()

ft = time.time()
for i in range(10000):
    opy = copy.deepcopy(ship)
print("It took", time.time()-ft)


ft = time.time()
for i in range(10000):
    ship2 = Boat()
print("It took", time.time()-ft)
```

With an output of this

```
It took 0.039893150329589844
It took 0.0019941329956054688
```